# RegEx, matching group of html tags

Tags: regex

Lets say we have some html like this:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <h2>Match group</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Match group 2</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Match group n</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>NOMATCH</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can we extract all groups of h2 and ul tags where h2 tag contains the word *match*? Basically I need to add a container div to this group of elements like this:

```
<div id="container">
<h2>Match group 1></h2><ul>...</ul>
<h2>Match group 1></h2><ul>...</ul>
<h2>Match group N></h2><ul>...</ul>
</div>
<h2>NOMATCH</h2>
<ul>...</ul>
```

H2 and ul tags may contain any number of html attributes.

This is what I got so far:
https://regex101.com/r/mR2fT7/1

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Don't do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said you more need a DOM parser to achieve this. DOM parser is the right tool for this job. But just to answer your question, if input string structure remains the same all the time, you can extract desired `h2 + ul` groups in this way:

```
(<h2>(?=[^<]*?(?i:match))[^<]+<\/h2>\s*<ul>[\s\S]*?<\/ul>)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN7bN0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DOM` parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$headlines = $xpath->query("//h2[contains(., 'Match')]");
print_r($headlines);
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/3SnqGX).